# Uncaught ReferenceError: $function is not defined

Tags: javascript, html, referenceerror

The purpose of this function is to load a timestamp by default into a form element, but it appears this javascript function is never loaded when the HTML renders.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script type=”text/javascript”>
  function Timestamp() {
    const currentTime = new Date();
    var year = currentTime.getFullYear();
    var month = currentTime.getMonth();
    var day = currentTime.getDate();
    var dash = "-";
    var space = " ";
    var colon = ":";
    var hour = currentTime.getHours();
    var minutes = currentTime.getMinutes();
    var seconds = currentTime.getSeconds();
    var timestamp = year.concat(dash, month, dash, day, space, hour, colon, minutes, colon, seconds);
    document.getElementById("curr").innerHTML = timestamp;
    console.log(timestamp);
  }
</script>

<head>
  <title>Create New Reservation</title>
</head>

<body onload="Timestamp()">
  <h1>Enter Reservation Details</h1>
  <h3>Current Time: <span id="curr"></span></h3>
  <form method="post" action="form.php">
    <fieldset>
      <label>Current Time</label>
      <type="text" />
      <input type="text" id="occurred" name="occurred">


  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

The console outputs the following error:

"Uncaught ReferenceError: Timestamp is not defined"

Comment: Try moving the script into the `<head>` and potentially changing the `type=”text/javascript”` to use normal double quotes.  Or just remove that attribute.  It's not required on simple scripts anymore.

Comment: `<html>` can only have `<head>` and `<body>` children. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/html

Comment: `year` is a number and not a string, so has no `concat` method. `year.toString().concat(...`. Or use the available [DateTimeFormat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/DateTimeFormat) object.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

”text/javascript” will not work.  use "text/javascript"

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>


<head>
  <title>Create New Reservation</title>
</head>

<body onload="Timestamp()">
  <h1>Enter Reservation Details</h1>
  <h3>Current Time: <span id="curr"></span></h3>
  <form method="post" action="form.php">
    
      <label>Current Time</label>
      <type="text" />
      <input type="text" id="occurred" name="occurred">


  </form>
  <script>
  function Timestamp() {
    const currentTime = new Date();
    var year = currentTime.getFullYear();
    var month = currentTime.getMonth();
    var day = currentTime.getDate();
    var dash = "-";
    var space = " ";
    var colon = ":";
    var hour = currentTime.getHours();
    var minutes = currentTime.getMinutes();
    var seconds = currentTime.getSeconds();
   var timestamp = year + dash + month + dash+ day+ space+ hour+ colon+ minutes+ colon+ seconds;
    document.getElementById("curr").innerHTML = timestamp;
    console.log(timestamp);
  }
  </script>
 
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I didn't immediately see it, the issue being "smart quotes" vs regular quotes. OP should use an IDE that doesn't default to these (or maybe copy paste from a site that has them, been bitten by this before).